# CSS Radial Gradient Mask Causing Text Visibility Issue in Overlapping Divs

Tags: html, css

I have a waves in css:
[image]

made with html:

```
<div>
  <div class="box w-[full] h-[10rem] bg-indigo-500"></div>
  <div class="box1 w-[full] h-[10rem] bg-indigo-800 mt-[-10rem] relative z-0">
    <div class="z-10 absolute">
      <p>Made for learning purposes</p>
      <p>Code at <a href="">github</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
.box {
  --mask: radial-gradient(42.43px at 50% 60px, #000 99%, #0000 101%)
      calc(50% - 60px) 0/120px 100%,
    radial-gradient(42.43px at 50% -30px, #0000 99%, #000 101%) 50% 30px/120px
      100% repeat-x;
  -webkit-mask: var(--mask);
  mask: var(--mask);
}
.box1 {
  --mask: radial-gradient(42.43px at 50% 60px, #000 99%, #0000 101%)
      calc(50% - 60px) 0/120px 100%,
    radial-gradient(42.43px at 50% -30px, #0000 99%, #000 101%) 50% 30px/120px
      100% repeat-x;
  -webkit-mask: var(--mask);
  mask: var(--mask);
  margin-left: -110px;
}
```

the problem is that i cant see the text inside the darker div. I tried z-index and position absolute and relative. Do you know how to make it visible using tailwind css?

Comment: I made a snippet of your code but it shows nothing.  You appear to have declared `--mask` multiple times

Comment: why using a negative margin-left? if you need to shift the position of the mask, you need to adjust the position